# Ruby on Rails Getting name can't be blank error when trying to add new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am a Ruby on Rails newbie, and am trying to put into practice some of the tutorials I have been following.

I am currently trying to get a basic user signup working.

When the signup form is completed and submitted, the Firstname and Lastname fields are blanked out and I get two error messages (I also get a failing error when running the cucumber tests):

- Firstname can't be blank
- Lastname can't be blank

I think I have missed something fairly obvious with the authentication code, but can't spot what I have missed.

All my code is on my [github account](https://github.com/nstoker/ScoutHut)

### Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

### Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname, :middlename
  validates :firstname, :presence =>true
  validates :lastname, :presence=>true
  validates :email, :presence=>true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  before_validation :downcase_email

  def name
    [firstname, middlename, lastname].compact.join(' ')
  end

  private
    def downcase_email
      self.email = self.email.downcase if self.email.present?
    end
end
```

### Views User

## new.erb.rb

```
<h1>New user</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

### _form.rb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :middlename %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :middlename %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: looks like you're using devise authentication and you have registrable in your model however, i don't see correct setup of your form.  The following assumes that you have set "@user" correctly.
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
if you have followed the devise tutorial your new form should be showing(rake routes):
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new

Comment: Also, i have never used "new.erb.rb" but, always used new.html.rb

Comment: The usual practice is to use ".html.erb" for naming template files which indicates Embedded Ruby (".erb") instead of 'just' Ruby (".rb")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using devise, you can try running `rails generate devise:views`. This will generate all of the correct views for everything devise does. You might want to save the forms that you already have in case Devise tries to override them, though.

Comment: I was, and went back to first principles for the app.